# java - Computing file size from URL

Tags: java

I have a lot of URLs. I want to calculate the total files size of all those Urls. I don't want to download it just calculate the size. I used the following approach it's working 
but it will take long time. Please can anyone suggest me the best approach than this..

Computing the file size.

```
int getFileSize(URL url) {

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
            conn.getInputStream();
            return conn.getContentLength();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return -1;
        } finally {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As `HttpURLConnection.getContentLength()` returns the value of the `content-length header` field, this may `return -1` if it has not been set.

So unless you can write something on the server which reads the files size, then you may have to read the entire inputstream.

Comment: Sorry i didn't get you. could you explain with code.

Comment: If all of your urls are on the same server, then maybe implement some servlet to simply give you the file size of a particular file.

Comment: Yes. All Urls are in same server. I am new to servlets. could you help me on this

Comment: try http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html or http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseWTP/article.html

Answer (score 0):

HEAD requests is your only way without actually downloading everything unless you have access to the file system on the server (which I doubt).

You can't get the size of a document without asking for it.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is seems OK to me. You can't find out the length without asking the server. You could launch all of the HEAD requests in parallel to reduce the elapsed time - doing them sequentially means your program will wait for responses for most of the time.

If there is no Content-Length, then [this](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.4) explains how to calculate the message body length. So do a HEAD, then if you get a -1, do a GET and work out the length from that.